# Repositories do not respond when using pydriller to extract data from a specific branch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, github, pydrill

I am using pydriller to extract metrics from certain github repos.
while implementing a branch specific extraction function as you can see in the following code.
the terminal returns the following errors: Problem reading repository at repoX

```
from pydriller import RepositoryMining
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

end_date = datetime.now()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=10) - relativedelta(years=0)

# Replace this path with your own repository of interest
paths = ['repoX']

branch_name = "main"  # Replace with the desired branch name

commits = []

for path in paths:
    try:
        for commit in RepositoryMining(path, credentials=("username", "access_token"), since=start_date, to=end_date, only_in_branch=branch_name).traverse_commits():
            hash = commit.hash
            for f in commit.modified_files:
                record = {
                    'hash': hash,
                    'message': commit.msg,
                    'author_name': commit.author.name,
                    'author_email': commit.author.email,
                    'author_date': commit.author_date,
                    'author_tz': commit.author_timezone,
                    'committer_name': commit.committer.name,
                    'committer_email': commit.committer.email,
                    'committer_date': commit.committer_date,
                    'committer_tz': commit.committer_timezone,
                    'in_main': commit.in_main_branch,
                    'is_merge': commit.merge,
                    'num_deletes': commit.deletions,
                    'num_inserts': commit.insertions,
                    'net_lines': commit.insertions - commit.deletions,
                    'num_files': commit.files,
                    'branches': ', '.join(commit.branches),
                    'filename': f.filename,
                    'old_path': f.old_path,
                    'new_path': f.new_path,
                    'project_name': commit.project_name,
                    'project_path': commit.project_path,
                    'parents': ', '.join(commit.parents),
                }
                # Omitted: modified_files (list), project_path, project_name
                commits.append(record)
    except Exception:
        print('Problem reading repository at ' + path)
        continue

# Save it to FileCommits.csv
df_file_commits = pd.DataFrame(commits)
df_file_commits.to_csv('FileCommits.csv')
```

I tried using my name and generating a git personal token sadly the problem persists.
removing the branch specific function extracts the necessary functions.
I also tried using Repository instead of RepositoryMining.
P.S: the data extracted is going to imported into elasticSearch.